# C# Screen Scraper - Handle long uri's

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

I'm building a html screen scraper, which parses urls, and then compare those with a set of other urls.

The comparison is done with Uri.AbsoluteUri or Uri.Host.

My problem is that when i'm creating a new Uri (new Uri(url)), an UriFormatException is thrown when the url is to long, or contains to many slashes.

Since my predefined set of urls contains several (to) long urls, I cannot just use substring to only fetch a part of the url.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Uri.TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx) to check if the URI is valid before you `new` it.

You should not get an exception on a url this is so short. The folowing program runs well on VS2008:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298985/c-screen-scraper-handle-long-uris/c-screen-scraper-handle-long-uris/c-screen-scraper-handle-long-uris/c-screen-scraper-handle-long-uris/c-screen-scraper-handle-long-uris/c-screen-scraper-handle-long-uris/c-screen-scraper-handle-long-uris/c-screen-scraper-handle-long-uris/");
    Uri uri2 = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298985/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Yes i know, but if that fails, i cannot compare that uri to my list. What i would want is to just "disable" those checks when creating a new Uri.

Comment: How long are your "too long" uris? Are you sure they are actually valid?

Comment: The uri i'm testing is completely valid, only allowed characters. The length is 277 chars.

Comment: See my sample. It's 315 chars long and does not throw an exception. How many slashes does your url have that throws an exception?

Comment: I think i found the problem. The hostname contained about 200 characters.